# Node.js - Is it a good practice to export all files in index.js for each directory?

Tags: node.js

```js
// configs/index.js
module.exports = {
  AppConfig: require('./app-config'),
  AuthConfig: require('./auth-config'),
  DbConfig: require('./database-config'),
};

// controllers/some-controller.js
const { AppConfig } = require('../configs');

// tests/some-test.spec.js
// it fails because the controller require() the root index.js and it runs all exported files implicitly.
const SomeController = require('../controllers/some-controller');
```

The above example works well in development, but it fails in unit testing using `mocha` because it runs all exported files implicitly. My workaround is to import the file directly like this `require('../configs/app-config')`. **What is your preferred solution? Should I export all files at all? Is it a good practice?**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exporting/importing each of the "sub-configs", you could create a `ConfigService`-class that encapsulates access to the config files. Something like:

```
const lodash = require('lodash');

export class ConfigService {

    static configuration = ConfigService.initConfig();

    static get(key) {
        return _.get(ConfigService.configuration, key);
    }
    // you can remove this if you don't want to support adding/changing configs at runtime
    static add(key, val) {
        if (ConfigService.configuration[key]) {
            throw new Error(`Could not add a new configuration key <${key}>. This key exists already!`);
        }
        _.set(ConfigService.configuration, key, val);
    }

    static initConfig() {
        ConfigService.configuration = {
            AppConfig: require('./app-config'),
            AuthConfig: require('./auth-config'),
            DbConfig: require('./database-config'),
        }
    }

}
```

Usage is rather simply and it even allows you to mock config values (by stubbing the `get`-method) in your unit-tests:

```
class DbController {

    constructor() {
        this.dbHost = ConfigService.get('DbConfig').dbHost;
        // ...
    }
}
```